# How do I make my java program to accept an excel file given in the command line?

Tags: java

I want to make my program accept the file name given in the command line when I run this as an executable jar file. In my below code, I have hard coded the file name as report.xlsx. For example I want it to accept the file using the command, `java -jar Vnp.java fileName.xlsx`

```js
  public ArrayList < String > getReports() throws IOException {
        ArrayList < String > reports = new ArrayList < String > ();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("reports.xlsx"));
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        sheet = workbook.getSheet("sheet1");
        int rowCount = sheet.getFirstRowNum() + sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
        reportCount = rowCount;
        int colCount = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        if (colCount > 1) {
            System.out.println("The number of columns are more than 1. Please input only one column with the report keys");
        } else if (colCount == 1) {
            System.out.println("Number of reports given: " + rowCount);
            for (int rNum = 1; rNum <= rowCount; rNum++) {

                for (int cNum = 0; cNum < colCount; cNum++) {

                    reports.add(getCellData("sheet1", cNum, rNum));
                }
            }
        }
        return reports;
    }
```

Comment: *"I want it to accept the file"* what do you mean with *accepting a file*? Do you simply want to use the command line argument for the filename? Then you should have a look at your main method where command line arguments are given to your code (in the `String` array which is the method's parameter)

Comment: What's the issue? Have you tried getting use of `public static void main(String[] args)` ? Those are you arguments,

Comment: why is this tagged "selenium"? ... it doesn't even mention selenium at all

Comment: Hi @CoreyGoldberg. This is a part of a selenium script that I am working on. If I tag it, it can cover more SOs and can help me get more answers or an answer quickly. Anyways i have got one now. Thanks a lot for taking your time and trying to help me out though. Really appreciate it.

Comment: but it doesn't have anything to do with selenium.  I am removing those tags.  Please don't add irrelevant tags just to reach more viewers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add the string param to method for file name

```
public ArrayList < String > getReports(String filename) throws IOException {
     ArrayList < String > reports = new ArrayList < String > ();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
     ...........
}
```

if calling from main then pass the first index :

```
public static void main(String a[]){
  if(a.length == 0)//check if command line args passed
   System.exit(0);//if not then exit
  ArrayList<String> list = obj.getReports(a[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**can you try this one. it is working**
https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-excel-file-apache-poi/

Comment: Hi @Vipin. Thanks a lot for taking you time and helping me out. The above link was useful.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.